# gradle proj sync failed, every methods tried

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

error message:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Alexs/AndroidStudioProjects/applicationone/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.">Show Details</a>
```

This error is along with tons of similar dependencies errors.

methods tried:

1. clear caches
2. reinstall android studio
3. download the latest Gradle and replace the original one.

**4. Play with the build.gradle file and add several lines**

I am just a student who wants to start some android project with java.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my up-level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here's my gradle file for my proj:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven {
       url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" // -------------------> Add this
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alexs.applicationone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2-alpha1'
}
```

my sdk version is 27 btw.

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: shall i know your compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: add 'GRADLE_USER_HOME' system user environment variable with gradle installation path in your system.

Comment: @PoovarasanSelvaraj it's Android API 27. thanks.

Comment: @rupinderjeet i tried but it didn't work for my case.

Comment: btw i am living in china so i have the firewall... i m already using vpn so downloading the dependencies shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: it is due to version mismatch for buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" & your appcompat version try replacing it with this **implementation com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2**

Answer (score 0):

Add `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` to build.gradle file like below :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" // -------------------> Add this
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alexs.applicationone"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Nikunj. I tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your top-level `build.gradle` file, not the app module one you posted, add the following block:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Or in your `app/build.gradle` file (the one you posted) add the `google` repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
       url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

Comment: I see, sorry for that. I tried your configuration and I could reproduce the error you are facing, with the same stacktrace. It fixed for me.